# Why is my localization in wordpress not working?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a theme.

All words and phrases are using either:

```
__('Word Here','mythemelocalpath')
```

or

```
_e('Word Here','mythemelocalpath')
```

I have made a folder called languages within the my new themes folder.

I created a .mo and .po and .pot file with poedit and placed them within the languages folder which is within my new theme folder.

The .mo, .po, .pot files are after the localization which is example: de_DE.mo

I then wrote this bit of code within the functions.php:

```
function mycustom_load_localization() {

    // Retrieve the directory for the localization files
    load_theme_textdomain( 'mythemelocalpath', TEMPPATH.'/languages' );

} // end custom_theme_setup
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mycustom_load_localization');
```

I then enter the wp-config.php file and change the WP_LANG to de_DE

But for some reason its not working?

Can someone shed some light on this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'mythemelocalpath', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/' );
```

instead of

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'mythemelocalpath', TEMPPATH.'/languages' );
```

where `get_stylesheet_directory()` should give you the stylesheet directory path and it should be *child theme save* ;-)

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory

Comment: what about `/languages/` instead of `/languages`? I updated the answer.

Comment: I guess it's just a minor thing that is preventing this working ;-)

Comment: Still not working. Is it because I am using it as a function? Should i use it without a function?

Comment: what's inside languages/ ?

Comment: en_GB.mo, en_GB.po, en_GB.pot, de_DE.mo, de_DE.po

Comment: ok that looks right. I guess you have double checked the text domain 'mythemelocalpath'.

Comment: what do you mean double checked? do you mean make sure the file is located in the theme folder?

Comment: just that you are using the same textdomain used in _e and what is used in load_theme_textdomain. You could also try to find some mature TwentyTwelve de_DE.mo file and try it on your theme (try fx `_e( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' )` and change your textdomain to twentytwelve), if you can get it to work, then there might be some problem with your .mo file.